# using tinyreq with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying https://github.com/IonicaBizau/tinyreq. Looking at the docs, I have no problem running the example using callbacks.

```
const tinyreq = require("tinyreq");

// Make a request to example.com
tinyreq("http://example.com/", (err, body) => {
    console.log(err || body);
});
```

But the example as listed using a **promises** syntax gives no output.

```
// Make a request with custom headers
// Using a promise
tinyreq({
    url: "http://example.com/"
  , headers: {
        "user-agent": "Crawler/1.0"
    }
}).then(body => {
    console.log(body);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I am using node version 8.3.0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug, indeed! Thanks!

---

Addressed [here](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/tinyreq/pull/27/commits/c7a0b5aab6eac8dc4d52fe37a78ba338c32655b5). Tinyreq does not store the response body unless a callback is provided. Now, when calling `then` Tinyreq knows that it has to store the response body.

This was the fix:

```
str.then = fn => {
 callback = callback || noop
  return opt_callback._.then(fn)
}
```